# Terraform erro no provider invalid character ':'

Tags: prisma, cloud

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro no `Terraform`.

> Error: invalid character ':' after top-level value with provider["registry.terraform.io/paloaltonetworks/prismacloud"],
> on main.tf line 11, in provider "prismacloud":   11: provider
> "prismacloud" {

Não importa o que eu mande ele criar ele dá esse erro, até mesmo se eu rodo um `init` ele apresenta esse erro, mas se eu comentar o código de criação de recurso e rodar o `plan`, ele consegue rodar o comando, claro que não cria nada, mas o que acho mais estranho é que a linha que da o erro esta antes do código de criação de recurso, esta no bloco do `provider`, que só da erro se eu adiciono algum código para criação.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    prismacloud = {
      source = "PaloAltoNetworks/prismacloud"
      version = "~>1.1.0"
    }
  }
}
 /*Configure the prismacloud provider*/
provider "prismacloud" {
    json_config_file = ".prismacloud_auth.json"
}
resource "prismacloud_account_group" "tf-test" {
    name = "tf-test"
    description = "Made by Terraform"
}
```

O arquivo .prismacloud_auth.json tem o seguinte coonteudo

***"url": "api.eu.prismacloud.io"
"username": "48f8...",
"password": "REjk...",
"protocol": "https"***

Comment: Poderia compartilhar o código do terraform? Seria interessante incluir os arquivos `prismacloud_auth.json` e mais o que tiver de subsídios para poder depurar o problema.

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/527399/edit).

Comment: Poderia postar o `prismacloud_auth.json` completo?

Comment: Se for só isso, está faltando uma virgula no seu json. Antes do `"username"`.

Comment: Consegui achar a solução, por algum motivo o Terraform não consegue fazer a autenticação utilizando o arquivo Json. Com as informações inseridas no script foi possivel me logar e posteriormente executar os codigos.

Answer (score -1):

O problema não parece estar no código fornecido, e sim no arquivo `.prismacloud_auth.json`.

Uma maneira simples de validar se o seu script `terraform` está formatado corretamente, que o script terraform é válido e consistente. é executando o comando:

```
terraform validate
```

esta é a saída da execução do comando `terraform validate` para o seu código:

> Success! The configuration is valid.

Saiba mais sobre o comando [`terraform validate`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/validate.html).

---

Repare que no trecho do conteúdo do arquivo que postou, está faltando uma vírgula entre os atributos `url` e `username`. Essa é a causa raiz do seu problema.

Se corrigir o arquivo para conter um `json` válido o problema será resolvido.
Ex:

***.prismacloud_auth.json***

```
{
    "url": "api.eu.prismacloud.io",
    "username": "48f8...",
    "password": "REjk...",
    "protocol": "https"
}
```

Depois de corrigir o arquivo .json, basta executar um `plan` novamente.

```
terraform plan
```

Agora será exibido a estrutura de sua infra.

Após verificar as mudanças, basta provisionar a infra com o comando:

```
terraform apply
```

Após a execução deste comando sua infra estará provisionada.

Segue a [documentação](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PaloAltoNetworks/prismacloud/latest/docs) do `provider` prismacloud para utilização com o `Terraform`.